# java websocket client "leaving read() loop with no demand"

Tags: java, websocket

I'm working on implementing a simple WebSocket client for the [binance websocket streaming API](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#general-wss-information), which is a rather simple API requiring no authentication or protocol overhead once connected. However when I use the `java.net.http.WebSocket` implementation I fail to receive inbound message notifications to my `WebSocket.Listener`. I have already verified the API works as expected using the 2 other reference implementations below (one cli and one javascript). I am using OpenJDK version 11.0.11+9

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

For reference my implementation can be seen at https://gist.github.com/erickj/5b6dad4a80a8d77b4e9a86e16aa4f131#file-binancewebsocketclient-java

As far as I can tell from debugging the java WebSocket implementation (with -Djdk.internal.httpclient.debug=true) it is exiting its read loop with message (see [full log output here](https://gist.github.com/erickj/5b6dad4a80a8d77b4e9a86e16aa4f131#file-log-txt-L471-L472)):

```
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [4s 175ms] SocketTube(1) no more demand for reading
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [3s 56ms] SocketTube(1) leaving read() loop with no demand Reading: [ops=0, demand=0, stopped=false], Writing: [ops=0, demand=1]
```

After the log messages above no other messages are received by the WebSocket.Listener. I have confirmed however with `ngrep` that data continues to be sent on the socket from the server to my client.

I've traced the above log messages re: "no more demand for reading" to code handling the read loop in `jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube#read`:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11%2B28/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/SocketTube.java#L872

From a brief read through the code, it's not clear to me where the issue is, however the state management of the read loop, particularly the check on [`demand.tryDecrement()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11%2B28/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/SocketTube.java#L818) (and my other working implementations, see below) make me suspect the issue is actually with openjdk WebSocket implementation. Unfortunately I don't know enough about the implementation or the websocket protocol to debug further without much more investigation.

Am I missing something obvious?

---

From above... I have confirmed that there is nothing wrong with the API endpoint with 2 other implementations (one cli client and one from browser javascript), as follows:

```
$ websocat wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/adausdt@trade
```

```js
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/adausdt@trade");
ws.onmessage = (e) => { console.log("onmessage: ", e); };
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer... I previously had not fully understood the purpose of `WebSocket#request` (and IMO is a terribly named and confusing aspect of the WebSocket API).

I needed to increment the "expected request" counter by at least 1 after creating the connection. [Per the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/WebSocket.html#request(long)):

> To control receiving of messages, a WebSocket maintains an internal counter. This counter's value is a number of times the WebSocket has yet to invoke a receive method. While this counter is zero the WebSocket does not invoke receive methods. The counter is incremented by n when request(n) is called. The counter is decremented by one when the WebSocket invokes a receive method. onOpen and onError are not receive methods. WebSocket invokes onOpen prior to any other methods on the listener. WebSocket invokes onOpen at most once. WebSocket may invoke onError at any given time. If the WebSocket invokes onError or onClose, then no further listener's methods will be invoked, no matter the value of the counter. For a newly built WebSocket the counter is zero.

Basically I added the `ws.request` call to the CompletableFuture callback in order to allow calls to WebSocket.Listener to proceed.

```
    wsFuture.thenAccept(ws -> {
          ws.request(1);
          log("created websocket: %s", ws);
        });
```